# How to check if the page is a publishing page in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SP 2010/2013, how can I check in JavaScript whether the current page is a publishing page, one where end users can edit and publish, or if it's a layout page like `view all content`, `site settings`, etc... Maybe if I can check the page layout/content type, that might work too.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check if the page is a publishing page is via JSOM. The object _spPageContextInfo has list id and list item id to find the item's content type. The publishing page content types are Page, Article Page, Welcome Page and Error Page. If the item's content type is one of these then its a publishing page.

The JSOM code below is just an example to check if the page is a publishing page.

```
var clientContext;
function retrieveListItems() {

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>' + _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(ContentType)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var oContentType = oListItem.get_contentType();
        clientContext.load(oContentType);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            (function (oContentType) {
                return function () {
                    var contentType = oContentType.get_name();
                    console.log("ContentType: " + contentType);
                    if(contentType === 'Page' || contentType === 'Welcome Page' || contentType === 'Article Page' || contentType === 'Error Page' )
                        console.log("The page is a publishing page");
                    else
                        console.log("The page is NOT a publishing page");
                };
            }(oContentType)),
            function () {
                console.log("No Success");
            }
        );
    }

    console.log(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
retrieveListItems();
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Application pages (i.e. "back-office pages", i.e. all pages Inside "_layouts") are hard-coded page without any content type (they're not in a doc lib).
You can simply check the URL of the page: if it contains "_layouts", you can be sure it's an application page, i.e. non editable.

There's only one exception: in SP2013, you may get the infamous start.aspx page (related to the infamous Minimal Download Strategy feature, activated by default on Team sites). If you're on "_layouts/15/start.aspx", you cannot assume you're on an application page for real. You then need to test (i.e. look for "_layouts") in the part of the URL *after* *#*.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint publishing pages are by default stored in the "Pages" library that the system creates when you activate the Publishing feature.  Thus, if the path/url includes "/Pages/" it is probably a Publishing page.  But @Evariste is correct, if MDS is activated, then you have to deal with /_layouts/.